# How to set different resolution on different chart in netdata?

Tags: monitoring, statsd, netdata

I have setup a netdata server to monitor application metrics, and would like to use statsd to collect metrics data. After research some days, I still have no idea of how to set different resolution on different chart. 
For example, I would like to show total sales every hour, however the request count every minute. It seem netdata will only refresh the chart every one second(the global setting of 'update every'). So how to make netdata refresh total sales chart per hour(a lower resolution), and the total request count per minute? or I just misunderstood netdata/statsd? 
Thanks in advance.